# spring gateway server fail when gateway server protected witeh csrf and request content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring, security, cloud, csrf

## spring gateway server cannot get response from upsteam server when gateway server protected witeh csrf and request content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

there are two simple server.

### the 1st is gateway server.

it's only import gateway and security.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and it's security config like this. they are very simple. so i write them in the same class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll();
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        return http.build();
    }
    /**
     * add csrf cookie response on every response
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public WebFilter addCsrfTokenFilter() {
        return (exchange, next) -> Mono.just(exchange)
                .flatMap(ex -> ex.<Mono<CsrfToken>>getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName()))
                .doOnNext(ex -> {
                })
                .then(next.filter(exchange));
    }
}
```

the gateway routes

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: test
          uri: http://localhost:8888
          predicates:
            - Path=/test/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
```

## the 2nd is an upstream server

it is a simple web server

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class UpstreamApplication {


    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String postData(Dto dto) {
        return "post success";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UpstreamApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

the dto class has 2 properties a and b

```java
public class Dto {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

and i config the server start on port 8888

```yaml
server:
  port: 8888
```

and then ,i use post man to test them.
the 1st time ,i have no csrf value.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/test/test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'a=1' \
--data-urlencode 'b=2'
```

the server response the invalidate csrf token exception.
and then i get csrf token value from cookie values.
and then i send request with csrf header.

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/test/test' \
--header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: f8db31f3-8be6-4103-8e15-5ef4594a08f0' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=f8db31f3-8be6-4103-8e15-5ef4594a08f0' \
--data-urlencode 'a=1' \
--data-urlencode 'b=2'
```

the client is wait for response more than 3 minutes and not completed.

i test the other content type ,they are completed normal.

if the upstream server's function params is empty or the client request params is empty. it can be completed.

the test project is here https://github.com/ldwqh0/spring_gateway_csrf_bug